# After cloning a multiproject github repository in VS '17, compiling selected .csproj fails unless opened individually. How to fix?

Tags: asp.net

I have cloned the entire .Net Core Docs in Visual studio and I want to be able to use the git source control integrated in Visual Studio. There are maybe a hundred .csproj files that I can select from but the .sln of each individual project is missing which I think explains why Manage NuGet Packages for Solution is greyed. When I build and run one of the ASP .NET Core projects I get the error: Can't load 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Opening the .csproj file separately(double clicking the .csproj file in explorer to open VS) builds and runs fine and I think it is because the build and run button says start IIsExpress. Does someone know what setting to set so that I can work on files while the entire git repository is open so that I can sync my files to the repo? Does this have to do with the fact that no solution exists but opening .csproj files separately creates the .sln (I'm guessing)? [image] [image]

Comment: You probably noticed issues should be reported to Microsoft via their GitHub repo when you cloned it. So do that. Personally I think the sample projects should be separate from each other, so no need to use the solution to compile them all. It is more reasonable to analyze them one by one.

Comment: @LexLi in the markdown do you know what "name" means in segments like `[!code-csharp[](intro/samples/blah/blah/blah.cshtml.cs?name=snippet_rv&highlight=24-)]` The line includes the file in the markdown and the name says what part of the file to display but I don't know how. Do you?

Comment: @me see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/contribute/ops-crr/openpublishing/docs/partnerdocs/codesnippets        and specifically for name see here: https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/spec/docfx_flavored_markdown.html?tabs=tabid-1%2Ctabid-a#tag-name-representation-in-code-snippet-source-file